# Filtering multiple columns into one

Tags: excel-formula, office365

I have a table of permitted combination of Dimensions, similar to the one below:
[image: Table1]

I need to have Data Validation linked to specific Dim Type (so there will be one column named A and the user should be able to select everything from Dim1 Value **and** Dim2 Value where the Type is A.

In a second Data Validation cell (called "B"), I need to specify the valid combinations relating to A.
So if someone selects A as **123**, then in the column marked B they should be able to see only **ZZZ** and **RQO**.

I think the Data Validations can be achieved if I've got 'helper' columns, which I'm thinking is made up of `FILTER()` formulae, but I can't find the correct formula to list all A's in one column (regardless of whether they appear in Dim1 or Dim2), and then all B's in the adjoining one.

Note: I do not have the ability to change the data in the table itself (this will be pulled from my source material and I can't change this), but am resigned to writing VBA to sort the columns as a last resort.

Appreciate any help in solving this mess. Thanks

EXAMPLE DATA TABLE

```
Dim1 Type | Dim1 Value | Dim2 Type | Dim2 Value
A         | 123        | B         | ZZZ
A         | 234        | B         | ZZY
A         | 345        | B         | ZYX
A         | 456        | B         | YXW
A         | 567        | B         | XWU
A         | 567        | B         | WUT
A         | 678        | B         | UTS
A         | 789        | B         | TSR
A         | 890        | B         | SRQ
A         | 301        | B         | RQO
B         | RQO        | A         | 123
B         | SRQ        | A         | 234
B         | TSR        | A         | 345
B         | UTS        | A         | 456
B         | WUT        | A         | 567
B         | XWU        | A         | 567
B         | YXW        | A         | 678
B         | ZYX        | A         | 789
B         | ZZY        | A         | 890
B         | ZZZ        | A         | 301
```

Comment: you can add a sheet where you convert the table either through formulas or VBA and then reference your new converted table

Comment: @ForwardEd: Yes, that's a possibility. So I'd create a new table with all Dim Type A's in the first column, and the associated combinations next to it. I guess my question is "How?" I'd want the quickest solution (imagine the combinations have 5,000 entries). Would this be quicker as formula (and what would that formula be) or by VBA? I was thinking of ```FILTER()``` as the formula but can't find a suitable combination. Any ideas?

Comment: will every value in Dim2 Type Also be in Dim1 Type? Ie is is possible to have `C` in dim 2 Type but not have it as a Dim1 Type?

Comment: @ForwardEd: Let me answer this way: possible combinations _could_ be **A-B**, **A-C**, **A-D**, **A-E**, **A-F**, **A-G**, **B-C**, **B-D**, **B-E**, **B-F**, **B-G**, **C-D**, etc.

Comment: So a letter in Dim 2 will always be listed in DIM1?

Comment: For now, yes. But I can't guarantee this will be the case in the future. So I'm looking for an elegant solution to accommodate any variation if someone has a half-brained idea next year.

Comment: I've now written VBA to produce one table will all A's in column 1. This was on a sample of 2540 entries. With ```ScreenUpdating=False``` it took 25.5 seconds to produce this table. I'd need multiple tables if there are multiple variations. To add 1/2 a minute with each variation seems too much. There has to be a quicker way using formulae ... isn't there?